# Disable specific settings dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios4, settings.bundle

I am developing an iPhone app which uses `Settings.bundle` to let the user choose some options.

I have two questions regarding this:

1. How can I completely remove/hide some setting? (for instance if the app is running on iPhone 3G I want to hide settings regarding the compass)
2. How can I disable (fade) a setting? (for instance, I have two Toggle Switches and if the first is set to OFF the second one has no meaning and should be disabled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Your app cannot dynamically influence what is shown in the Settings app.